# How can I implement RxJava's combineLatest on Kotlin co-routines receive channel?

Tags: kotlin, reactive-programming, kotlinx.coroutines

I need to implement the following `.combineLatest()` extension function on a `ReceiveChannel`

```
suspend fun <A, B, R> ReceiveChannel<A>.combineLatest(
    otherSource: ReceiveChannel<B>,
    context: CoroutineContext = Unconfined,
    combineFunction: suspend (A, B) -> R
): ReceiveChannel<R> = produce(context) {
    // ?
}
```

I would like it to function just like RxJava's [`combineLatest()`](http://rxmarbles.com/#combineLatest).

How can I do this?

EDIT: So far I have this, but it's not working. The `sourceB.consumeEach{ }` block is never excecuted.

```
suspend fun <A, B, R> ReceiveChannel<A>.combineLatest(
    otherSource: ReceiveChannel<B>,
    context: CoroutineContext = Unconfined,
    combineFunction: suspend (A, B) -> R
): ReceiveChannel<R> = produce(context) {

    val sourceA: ReceiveChannel<A> = this@combineLatest
    val sourceB: ReceiveChannel<B> = otherSource

    var latestA: A? = null
    var latestB: B? = null

    sourceA.consumeEach { a ->
        latestA = a
        if (latestA != null && latestB != null) {
            send(combineFunction(latestA!!, latestB!!))
        }
    }

    sourceB.consumeEach { b ->
        latestB = b
        if (latestA != null && latestB != null) {
            send(combineFunction(latestA!!, latestB!!))
        }
    }
}
```

I also want to make sure that when the `ReceiveChannel<R>` returned by this function is closed (unsubscribed from), I want to make sure that the parent channels are closed properly.

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick! I am still confused why I can nest one `.consumeEach{ }` inside another `.consumeEach { }` - it seems unintuitive.

```
suspend fun <A, B, R> ReceiveChannel<A>.combineLatest(
    otherSource: ReceiveChannel<B>,
    context: CoroutineContext = Unconfined,
    combineFunction: suspend (A, B) -> R
): ReceiveChannel<R> = produce(context) {

    val sourceA: ReceiveChannel<A> = this@combineLatest
    val sourceB: ReceiveChannel<B> = otherSource

    val latestA = AtomicReference<A>()
    val latestB = AtomicReference<B>()

    var aInitialized = false
    var bInitialized = false

    sourceA.consumeEach { a ->
        latestA.set(a)
        aInitialized = true
        if (aInitialized && bInitialized) {
            send(combineFunction(latestA.get(), latestB.get()))
        }

        launch(coroutineContext) {
            sourceB.consumeEach { b ->
                latestB.set(b)
                bInitialized = true
                if (aInitialized && bInitialized) {
                    send(combineFunction(latestA.get(), latestB.get()))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you launch a new corountine on every consumption of sourceA elements, surely these will start to pile up and compete with each other? I would use select to listen to both channels in the same loop

Answer (score 0):

I understand this is an old question but here is a suggestion:

I would recommned using `.zip()` instead of nesting `.consumeEach`. Checkout the documentation [here](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.channels/zip.html).

Possible solution `sourceA.zip(sourceB).consumeEach{}` which produces an item of type Pair.